# Do i need to set up "high availablility" with the connection broker when i only have one Remote Terminal

Tags: networking, remote-access, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

At the moment i am setting up a remote server for some remote users within our company.  Im stuck as to whether i need to configure the connection broker to allow for high availability.

What are the benefits of doing this and is it an absolute requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HA broker is not a requirement. This is optional and needed only for high availability of broker in case of node failures (i.e.: you need close to 100% availability).

Comment: Here is a blog with more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2012/06/27/rd-connection-broker-high-availability-in-windows-server-2012.aspx